# Solving an integral with substitution method

Tags: calculus

I want a hint for the following integral:
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^{2}\sqrt{1- a^{2}+x^{2}}}$$
where $a$ is a real constant.

In fact, 
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^{2}\sqrt{1- a^{2}+x^{2}}} = -\frac{\sqrt{1- a^{2}+x^{2}}}{x(1- a^{2})}$$
why?

Comment: Are you sure the derivative of the right side is what in the integral?

Comment: yes, you can test it easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to solve appears to be to rewrite it as

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^3\sqrt{\frac{1-a^2}{x^2}+1}}$$

Now the substitution

$$u=(1-a^2)x^{-2}+1,du=2(a^2-1)x^{-3}dx$$

reduces the integral to

$$\frac1{2(a^2-1)}\int u^{-1/2}du$$

Comment: @kilimanjaro Honestly, I haven't considered $a=\pm1$, but it's easy to determine.  The integral simply becomes $\int\frac{dx}{x^2}|x|=\pm\int x^{-3}dx$ depending on if $x$ is positive or negative.  The above answer also assumed $x>0$.  If $x<0, \sqrt{x^2}=-x$ and follows similarly, leading to the answer given in the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

$$ \frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{1-a^2 + x^2}} = \frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{\frac{x^2-a^2+1}{x^2}}}$$

$$ =\frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{\frac{1-a^2}{x^2} + 1}} $$

Let $\theta = \frac{1-a^2}{x^2} + 1$

$$ \frac{d\theta}{dx} = \frac{-2(1-a^2)}{x^3} \ \implies \ dx =  \frac{-x^3}{2(1-a^2)} \ d\theta $$

The integral then reduces to:

$$ \frac{-1}{2(1-a^2)}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\theta}}\ \ d\theta =  \frac{-1}{2(1-a^2)} 2 \sqrt{\theta} + c= -\frac{\sqrt{1-a^2+x^2}}{x(1-a^2)} + c $$

$$ = \frac{\sqrt{1-a^2+x^2}}{x(a^2-1)} + c$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume a$\ne $$1 or-1$,Put $x$=$\sqrt {1-a^2}$$tan$$\theta$ and then simplify..

$\int \frac{dx}{x^{2}\sqrt{1- a^{2}+x^{2}}}$=$\int \frac{sec^2\theta d\theta}{({1-a^2})tan^2\theta sec\theta}$=$\int \frac{cos\theta d\theta}{({1-a^2})sin^2\theta}$=
$\int \frac{d(sin\theta)}{({1-a^2})sin^2\theta}$=$\frac{-1}{({1-a^2})sin\theta}$+c
=-$\frac{\sqrt{1-a^2+x^2}}{x(1-a^2)}$+c

Comment: then last solution is $\frac{1}{1-a^{2}}\sin{(\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{}1- a^{2}})}$, while i want to obtain $ $-\frac{\sqrt{1- a^{2}+x^{2}}}{x(1- a^{2})}$$.

Comment: @user ,Now check it out,I have solved it fully.

Comment: Even what you've got can be simplified to answer that you want to get.